# Cordova - Select multiple photos and send it to server

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova

I am using cordova-imagePicker Plugin to select multiple images and send it to server using fileTransfer.

By using plugin I can select multiple images from gallery and can display it on screen. Problem I facing is to get imageURI from displayed images .

Following is my code: js File

```
function getMultiplePhoto() {
          window.imagePicker.getPictures(
                function(results) {

                    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {                          
                        var parent = document.getElementById('images');                             
                        img = new Image();
                        img.style.display = 'block';
                        img.className = 'hi';
                        img.src = results[i];
                        parent.appendChild(img);                
                    }
                }, function (error) {
                    console.log('Error: ' + error);
                }, {
                    maximumImagesCount: 10,
                    width: 800

                }
            );
        }

function uploadMutipleImages() {    

                var items = document.getElementByClassName('hi').getAttribute("src");


                for(var i=0; i<items.length; i++) {
                    console.log(items[i]);

                }
```

HTML file

```
<div id="one" class="ui-content">
    <h3>Upload Multiple Images from gallery</h3>
        <p>
            <button data-role="none" onclick="getMultiplePhoto();" class="nightly-button"><i class="fa fa-picture-o"></i>Select Images</button>
            <br><br>                            
        </p>
        <div style="width:30%;height:30%;" id="images"></div>
        <br>
        <input type="button" data-role="none" style="float:left;" onclick="uploadMutipleImages()" class="nightly-button" data-theme="b" Value="Submit">                         
</div>
```

Error I am getting using above code: object "HTML" has no method getelementsbyclassname

Answer (score 0):

You are using `getElementByClassName`

You have to use `getElementsByClassName`

Answer (score 0):

```
 function uploadMutipleImages() {
   var items = document.getElementsByClassName('hi');
   for(var i=0; i<items.length; i++) {
     console.log(items[i].src);
   }
 }
```

Comment: You should describe the difference from the OP's question clear,  not just post code, without explaining the changes that were made.